# Restar dos valores en SQL Server y el resultado mostrarlo en una consulta

Tags: sql-server, sql

¿Cómo están?
tengo una consulta y me gustaría que me ayudaran.

Tengo una tabla de docentes con una columna llamada "Valor" y esta contiene varios registros de 25000 y otros de 15000

```
create table ListadoAporte(
IdDocente int primary key,
CCEmpleado int not null,
Docente varchar(80) not null,
Valor float not null, 
Fecha datetime default GETDATE()  
);

--SECUENCIAS 
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_ListadoAporte
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
NO CACHE;
```

Entonces lo que quiero hacer es que al realizar un Select de Salud este me traiga de la columna valor solo los 1.000 (mil pesos) y cuando realice el Select de servicio este me traiga los 3.000 (tres mil pesos)
sin importar que existan registros con valores de 25000 o 15000.

```
--Salud Informe  
select ListadoAporte.IdDocente, ListadoAporte.CCEmpleado, ListadoAporte.Docente, ListadoAporte.Fecha,  
convert(decimal(18,2),(ListadoAporte.Valor - 24000)) as Aporte from ListadoAporte
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
--aqui me trae los 1000 pero solo en los que tengan un valor de 25.000 mil en el otro que tiene valor de 15000 mil al restarle 24.000 mil el resultado es -9.000 y el resultado debe ser 14.000 mil

--Entonces lo otro fue con un if pero no me trae los datos que quiero me sigue rentando solo un valor, pareciera que el otro no me lo tomara.

```
DECLARE @Valor int  
IF (@Valor <= 25000)    
    BEGIN 
    SELECT CCEmpleado, Docente, Fecha, (Valor - 24000)
     as Valor  
    FROM ListadoAporte
    END
ELSE  
    BEGIN 
    SELECT CCEmpleado, Docente, Fecha, (Valor - 14000)
       as Valor 
    FROM ListadoAporte
    END
```

Solo necesito que alguien me de alguna idea o una guia que pueda ayudarme, ya que en programación lo que uno se pueda imaginar lo puede hacer en la realidad. Gracias.

--edit ---
en la tabla aportes los docentes hacen un aporte de 25.000 mil pesos pero yo quiero tomar de los 25.000 mil pesos solamente 1.000 y en servicios solamente 3.000 mil pesos. **Pero el problema sería que algunos docentes solo aportan 15.000 mil pesos. y quiero un select que me traiga los 1.000 y otro select que me traiga los 3.000 sin importar que tengan un valor de 15 mil o 25 mil pesos.**

Comment: Para poder ayudarte necesitas formular la pregunta de forma completa : es decir debes incluir estructura de las tablas y su relación . Además debes colocar que has intentado.

Comment: ok, ya lo agrego

Comment: Lo lei varias veces y no entendi la pregunta, por favor trata de ser mas especifico en lo que necesitas. ¿Qué es eso de los 1.000 y los 3.000?. Saludos.

Comment: es el aporte que hace el docente en salud y en servicio, los 1000 pesos (mil pesos)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que tu quieres es realizar una operación si el valor es uno y otra si el valor es otro, por lo que sugiero que utilices la sentencia [`case`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), que permite hacer justamente lo que tu buscas.

Una forma de hacerlo es tomando en cuenta si el valor es menor a cierto límite y realizando una operación aritmética u otra:

```
select   ListadoAporte.IdDocente
       , ListadoAporte.CCEmpleado
       , ListadoAporte.Docente
       , ListadoAporte.Fecha
       , case 
           when ListadoAporte.Valor < 20000 then ListadoAporte.Valor - 14000
           else ListadoAporte.Valor - 24000
         end as Aporte 
  from ListadoAporte
```

La ventaja de hacerlo de esta manera es que, si hay otros valores que no sean exactamente 25000 o 15000, igual devolverá algunos valores.

Otra manera de hacerlo es tomando directamente los valores exactos y devolviendo, igualmente, un valor exacto (sin operación aritmética)., algo como:

```
select   ListadoAporte.IdDocente
       , ListadoAporte.CCEmpleado
       , ListadoAporte.Docente
       , ListadoAporte.Fecha
       , case ListadoAporte.Valor
           when 15000 then 1000
           when 25000 then 3000
         end as Aporte 
  from ListadoAporte
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu solución, la verdad me ha servido mucho ^^ estoy muy agradecido, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Una solución que encontré fue la siguiente

```
-- Salud Informe (aporte Docente)
select ListadoAporte.Fecha, ListadoAporte.CodEmpleado, ListadoAporte.Empleado as Docente, 
(ListadoAporte.Valor - 24000) as Aporte 
from ListadoAporte
where Valor like '%25000%'

select ListadoAporte.Fecha, ListadoAporte.CodEmpleado, ListadoAporte.Empleado as Docente, 
(ListadoAporte.Valor - 14000) as Aporte 
from ListadoAporte
where Valor like '%15000%'
```

pero me gustaría que todo se hiciera en un solo select, que fue la razón por la cual hice la pregunta